# Comparing DB technologies

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, comparison

I'm going to start a simple SaaS application and am considering which DB to go with(MSSQL, MySql, Oracle).

Can someone who experience it(actual use)point the pros and cons(performence,costs,easy to develop,easy to maintain) of each technology and recommend his favorite?

Comment: If you're starting SaaS, then I'm afraid that you already should have known the answers to the question you asked. On the other hand, I think this is the wrong place to be asking such a question - your financial situation is unknown, like your software's structure and what it does. I'm 99% sure you're going to go with MySQL because it costs 0 opposed to the other two. Anyway, good luck before this topic gets closed.

Comment: i'm looking for a simple table comparing the basic features and basic costs and directions (like MySql is only for small storage or doesn't support BI)

Comment: There's no "simple" table comparing those. There are so many engines for MySQL that are used for storage of huge amounts of data that cost pretty nice sum of $$ per year. There are also so many ways to scale your database that it makes your app follow that structure. If I were you, I'd probably hire a consulting company about this matter. They could help you on basis of your budget, requirement and application modification.

Answer (score 2):

This can't be answered in the context of which you've asked it.  There are a couple things that can make your decision easy (like cost) and I've included some information below that I hope you find useful.

1.) Budget

- If you don't have one or it's small, then MySQL is certainly your best option.  If you're storing a very small amount of information, you may be able to use a fairly inexpensive Oracle or SQL Server license, but as things get larger both of those technologies get expensive quickly.

2.) Data Storage

- This kinda goes along with the other, but as the size of your data increases you will likely want to start partitioning data.  This is free in MySQL, but an extremely expensive **option** with Oracle.  (I'm uncertain with SQL Server)  Oracle, charges per processor (and uses a core factor based on the architecture for processors over 2 cores) for partitioning and the list price of that is ~9k per.  If you want support it's ~20% of that per year.  What makes this worse is that you can only get partitioning in Oracle if you have Enterprise licenses which are quite expensive in themselves.  As you can see...it takes some $$$ to run a partitioned Oracle database.

3.) Management

- This will depend on prior experience.  I have the least experience on SQL Server, but find it's management tools easy to use.  Oracle has good tools but it's complexity can lend to a steeper learning curve.

Hope this information helps you in your decision.

Answer (score 0):

I have always felt that based solely on cost and performance, SQL Server is the best database engine on the market. I have several SQL Server instances that I set up many years ago and I have not ever had to more than ensure that daily backups were occurring. No need for DBAs to monitor and adjust the databases like DB2 and Oracle both seem to require.